# Can't release camera safely

Tags: android, camera, release, preview

I'm developing android camera app . It works fine , but when I try to release camera It says `Method called after cameraRelease()` . I use seperate `CameraPreview.java` class for preview . And initialize in on my `MainActivity.java` class by adding the following code inside `onCreate()`method .
`cameraPreviewLayout.addView(mPreview)`
 How to release camera safely ? I tried almost all ways on stackoverflow . But none of them worked for me . And answer is much more appreciated . Thanks in advance

Comment: If you could provide the code that you have tried along with the crashes you are recieving then I can help you

Comment: @lain I edited my question . Please Look at it

Comment: Ok and what is your crash i.e. what is the error and stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks @lain I solved my problem just adding a seperate CameraPreview class . And a constructor like `CameraPreview(context,camera)` .And I added it on MainaActivity like this `cameraLayout.addView(mPreview)`  . But now The App crashes when I close the app . I release the camera using the following method .`mCamera.stopPreview() mCamera.release() ` .  But when I close the app , it crashes and gives the following error . _Method called after Camera.release()_ . What Can I Do ?

Comment: Does the log show *which* method is called after release? When do you call Camera.release()? Do you set mCamera=null after release?